# Firefox Not Displaying CSS Header Correctly

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox seems to be the only browser that is not displaying my CSS header correctly.  It is supposed to have a navy blue border both above it and below it, which it displays correctly in Chrome and IE.  I'll post the CSS to the banner.  Firefox is showing the element as a "div clear" when I inspect it.

This is the webpage I am talking about: http://www.lymemd.org

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu {
  background: #8EBD0F;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
  #cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
  }
#cssmenu ul li a {
  width: 100%;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
 #cssmenu ul li a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
 height: 1px;
 background: #ffffff;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: .2;
}
 #cssmenu ul li.last > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have [mangled and invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lymemd.org&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  This is usually the real source of any cross-browser inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was simply missing a closing div tag - nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

What i would do is the following:

**1)** change the http://www.lymemd.org/images/headerbg.jpg image removing the bottom green border

**2)** change the #navArea style on stylenew1.css in the line 377 to:

```
#navArea {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8EBD0F;
    border-bottom: medium solid #455268;
    border-top: medium solid #455268;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I wish it helps you. Good luck!

Comment: Why were you downvoted?  Does that mean they don't think it will work?

Comment: All the CSS in the world cannot fix problems caused by bad HTML.

Comment: i don't know why was this downvoted, it is a perfectly good answer to me. It may not be the best but it is easy and it works.. if it helps you you can upvote or mark it as a good answer if you like :)

Comment: It was probably down-voted because it's not the correct answer.  The root problem was invalid HTML.

Comment: it is at least a practical answer, he can do that and have it working in 5 minutes.